# Get number of rows in a SQL Server table in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

There are 10 rows in `primary_student_table`.

When I execute the following code, the result was -1.

```
Dim count As Int16
con.Open()
query = "SELECT COUNT(roll) AS rollcount FROM primary_student_table WHERE admityear = 2011 AND batch = 1 "

cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)

count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
MsgBox(count)

con.Close()
```

What's the problem in the above code?

Comment: **1.** Off-topic, but still a potential problem: You are not calling `Dispose` on `cmd` and `con` after you've finished using them. **2.** Nothing wrong with `Int16`, but in VB.NET you'd usually refer to that type using the keyword `Short`. **3.** Ideally, you'd call `con.Open()` at the latest-possible moment, i.e. right before executing the command; i.e. generally, try to keep connections open for the shortest-possible time.

Comment: Besides the problems mention by 491243, `count(*)` and `count(row)` can produce different results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to replace

```
count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

with

```
count = cmd.ExecuteScalar
```

Like Robert Beaubien said in his comments

Answer (score 15):

You should be using `ExecuteScalar()` rather than `ExecuteNonQuery()` because you are fetching a value.

```
count = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
MsgBox(count.ToString())
```

- [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

For proper coding

- use `using` statement for proper object disposal
- use `try-catch` block to properly handle exceptions

Example Code:

```
Dim connStr As String = "connection string here"
Dim query As String = "SELECT COUNT(roll) AS rollcount FROM primary_student_table WHERE admityear = 2011 AND batch = 1"
Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = query
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        End With
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim count As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            MsgBox(count.ToString())
        Catch(ex As SqlException)
            ' put your exception here '
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you. No offence, is there any other technique with less coding?

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: I need it for my project. I am just a beginner and I can't fully understand this answer

Comment: dineshbabu is showing you the correct way to 1)get the information you want, and 2) detect when an error happens.  The change to your original code would simply be to use ExecuteScalar() insted of ExecuteNonQuery().  If you don't understand the rest of the code, ask a specific questions and someone will usually help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=dblms"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String

        Query = "Select * from dblms.accounts"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While READER.Read
            count = count + 1

        End While
      MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try
```

the value in count will be the number of rows in a table :) hope this helped